# MySQL SUM DISTINCT with Conditional

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by, sum, distinct

I need to gather sums using conditional statements as well as `DISTINCT` values
with a multiple `GROUP BY`. The example below is a simplified version of a much much more complex query.

**Because the real query is very large, I need to avoid having to drastically re-write the query.**

DATA

```
Contracts
    id  advertiser_id   status
    1   1               1
    2   2               1
    3   3               2
    4   1               1
```

A Query that's close

```
SELECT
    COUNT( DISTINCT advertiser_id ) AS advertiser_qty,
    COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS contract_qty,
    SUM( IF( status = 1, 1, 0 ) ) AS current_qty,
    SUM( IF( status = 2, 1, 0 ) ) AS expired_qty,
    SUM( IF( status = 3, 1, 0 ) ) AS other_qty
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM  `contracts`
        GROUP BY advertiser_id, id
) AS temp
```

Currently Returns

```
advertiser_qty  contract_qty    current_qty     expired_qty     other_qty   
3               4               3               1               0
```

Needs to Return

```
advertiser_qty  contract_qty    current_qty     expired_qty     other_qty   
3               4               2               1               0
```

Where `current_qty` is 2 which is the sum of records with `status = 1` for only `DISTINCT advertiser_ids` and each sum function will need the same fix.

I hope someone has a simple solution that can plug into the `SUM` functions.

-Thanks!!

Comment: what is `interested` ? its a column ?

Comment: (Fixed) Type-o, it was supposed to be status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT
    COUNT( DISTINCT advertiser_id ) AS advertiser_qty,
    COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS contract_qty,
    (select count(distinct advertiser_id) from contracts where status =1 
    ) AS current_qty,

   SUM( IF( status = 2, 1, 0 ) ) AS expired_qty,
   SUM( IF( status = 3, 1, 0 ) ) AS other_qty
   FROM (
   SELECT * FROM  `contracts`
   GROUP BY advertiser_id, id
   ) AS temp
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a82/7)

EDIT:

you may look for this without subselect.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT advertiser_id) AS advertiser_qty,
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS contract_qty,
        COUNT(DISTINCT advertiser_id , status = 1) AS current_qty,
        SUM(IF(status = 2, 1, 0)) AS expired_qty,
        SUM(IF(status = 3, 1, 0)) AS other_qty
 FROM (SELECT *
       FROM   `contracts`
       GROUP BY advertiser_id, id) AS temp
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c35/9)

Comment: Sorry, this won't work because I meant interested to be status.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, while this works for my abstract example, my real query is so large that it wouldn't be practical to put a complete subquery inside each SUM function. Basically, the real sub query is a few hundred lines long. The other thing I forgot to mention is that each SUM function will need the same logic. Is there any simple command like DISTINCT that can be applied to the conditional itself?

Comment: Not working, if I change them all to status 1 then current_qty returns 1 instead of 3 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c35/2/0

Comment: The query without subselect does not work. The demo fiddle itself show CURRENT_QTY as 3.